# SDL2-CS not working on OS X

Tags: mono, 32bit-64bit, sdl-2

I'm trying to use the SDL2 C# bindings (SDL2-CS), but for some reason, the Mac version of Mono isn't finding the library. `libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib` is installed in `/usr/local/lib/` and I've added it to `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I'm still getting a `System.DLLNotFoundException`. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, Mono is typically 32-bit, and installing through either MacPorts or a source build will yield a 64-bit binary. This could very well be the source of the problem, and you can check by setting `export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug`. If you see something along the lines of this:

```
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libSdl-2.0.0.dylib, 9): no suitable image found.
Did find: /opt/local/lib/libSdl-2.0.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture'.
```

then this is your problem right here. Compile SDL2 from source in 32-bit mode like so:

```
$ export CFLAGS="-arch i386"
$ export LDFLAGS="-arch i386"
$ ./configure
$ make
```

and to just to make sure that it's right, run:

```
$ file build/.libs/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
```

which should result in:

```
$ build/.libs/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

Now just `make install`, and you should be good to go!